# "google is not defined" and "google.maps.LatLng in undefined" errors when using Google Maps Isomorphic Javascript project

Tags: javascript, maps, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to use the Google Maps JavaScript API to create a map on my website, but I'm getting two errors: "google is not defined" and "google.maps.LatLng in undefined." I've tried searching for answers to these errors, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Below added issue facing screenshots

Screenshot - 1
[image]

Screenshot - 2
[image]

Screenshot - 3
[image]

Screenshot - 4
[image]

Comment: Do not use pictures alone for what can be represented in text format. Provide plain text. Screenshots, if needed, maybe added for more context.